# Change variable values while debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I was wondering if someone could tell me why I can't directly change the values of my array `idata` instead I have to expand `Raw View` as can be seen in the picture.

[image]

This does not make sense and is annoying since it took me a few minutes and some time on google to find out that strange behavior ..

Is there a way to change that such that I am able to change the values more intuitively?

Comment: The only thing I can think of, is to write your own visualizer plugin, or to add a quickwatch to the `_items` while you are debugging the code. Or use the immediate window, which I tend to do alot ;)